# Go to podcast page in iTunes Store

Tags: itunes, podcasts

In iTunes, I want to do something like this:

`Podcast > (podcast name) > right click > go to podcast page in iTunes Store`

Of course, there is no such option when I right click the podcast.

Is there a way to do something like that?

(I know I can search in iTunes Store by podcast name, or browse iTunes Store.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is a bit dodgy.

For some of the Podcasts, you can click the right-pointing arrow next to the Podcast's name (when selected) and that will take you too that podcast's iTunes page. This works for the Engadget podcast.

[image]

However, for the others, it will open up a page relating to the podcast in your default web browser. Is is what happens for the Stack Overflow podcast

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it and really, for some podcasts it opens podcast web page in browser, and for some it opens the podcast page in iTunes. Strange. I guess it depends on some podcast setting.

Answer (score 1):

If you go from the title row (The one with the down triangle) not the individual podcast
Then click on the right arrow ant the end of the podcast name tales me to iTunes if I got the podcast from iTunes.

Comment: I really do not understand what I should do. Could you please post a screen shot or a link to a page where it is explained?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to drag links from iTunes into a text editor, to get a link to the page. Try searching for the podcast, then dragging the link from iTunes to a text editor or other program.